# Inline generating dictionary: self referencing

Tags: python, dictionary

**The problem**: count occurrences of characters in a string.
**The solution**:

```
t1="acasa acasa e e bine bine bine si mai bine"
t2=list(t1)
t3={}
print(t2)
t3={ el:t2.count(el) for el in t2 if el not in t3}
print(t3)
```

When `t3` is being generated does the last conditional (`if el not in t3`) check make sense? 
Is the dictionary updated inside the generator?

Comment: You're reinventing [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: No it doesn't. You cannot reference the dictionary being created inside a dictionary comprehension

Comment: Not only are you reinventing  `collections.Counter` you are doing it in quadratic time instead of linear time, like a naive loop would be.

Comment: @sayse it doesn't matter. The *name* exists, but it's always referring to an empty dictionary, which makes the predicate pointless

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm answering the question, the dictionary isn't updated. `t3` is always referencing the empty dictionary that is totally unrelated to the dictionary created by the dictionary comprehension. It is a totally pointless check, not merely inefficient, it does nothing useful. You could have said `t3 = []` and it would do the same thing

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good point. It is legal but pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the standard library for this.

```
from collections import Counter

t1="acasa acasa e e bine bine bine si mai bine"
Counter(t1)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'a': 7,
         'c': 2,
         's': 3,
         ' ': 9,
         'e': 6,
         'b': 4,
         'i': 6,
         'n': 4,
         'm': 1})
```